# chromatic number of 2 graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

The join $G$ + $H$ is critical if and only if both $G$ and $H$ are critical

I know that $\chi(G+H)$ = $\chi(G)$ + $\chi(H)$ and since $G$ and $H$ are critical if we remove a vertex from $G$ or $H$ then  $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(H)$ decreases
How can I use this to prove the statement?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by deleting the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $u$ is a vertex of $G$, and $v$ a vertex of $H$, then:
$(G-u)+H = (G+H)-u$ and $G+(H-v) = (G+H)-v$

Using this we can prove the statement.

Assume $G$ and $H$ are critical, and let $w$ be any arbitrary vertex of $G+H$. Then $w$ is a vertex of either $G$ or $H$, it doesn't matter, so let's choose $w\in G$.
Tying together all the facts we collectively have, we obtain that: 
$\chi((G+H)-w) = \chi((G-w)+H) = \chi(G-w)+\chi(H) = \chi(G) - 1 +\chi(H) = \chi(G+H)-1$.

Since $w$ is arbitrary, we find that $G+H$ is critical, as needed.

Conversely, if we assume $G+H$ is critical, we do much the same thing.
Let $u$ be any arbitrary vertex of $G$, then:
$\chi(G-u) + \chi(H) = \chi((G-u)+H) = \chi((G+H)-u) = \chi(G+H) - 1 = \chi(G) + \chi(H) - 1$,
so subtracting $\chi(H)$ from both sides, we get $\chi(G-u) = \chi(G)-1$ as needed.